# Hiding/showing columns based on window size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ngx-datatable

I was wondering if there was any way to make ngx-datatable columns visible/invisible based on the window size, similar to the bootstrap class hidden-xs to hide things on extra small screens.

Comment: add any class to your columns which you want to show hide as per device width then write media query for device width and write style for hide and show.                                                                                                  
 `media only screen and (max-width:320px){.youclassname{display:none;}} /* this code hide your column in device which have 320px width and lower */`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a media query. 
**Example:**
Assign class names to td of columns you wish to hide based on certain widths. Lets say you have a class name -- .768hidables -- you can define a css as below:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
     .768hidables {
         display:None;
     }
}
```